# How to play a video starting from specific point on iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller, ios9

I'm playing video using **MPMoviePlayerController** and I need to play it starting from a given point by this code:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player;

[player setCurrentPlaybackTime:from];
[player setInitialPlaybackTime:from];
[player setEndPlaybackTime:to];

[player prepareToPlay];
[player play];
```

But it doesn't work, the video always plays from beginning.
I've seen on Apple Docs that **initialPlaybackTime** is deprecated in iOS 9 (as well as **endPlaybackTime**). Does it mean than it will not work on iOS 9? I tried to run this code on iOS 8.4, but the result is the same: the video always plays from the very beginning.

How to make it play from a given point?

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, @EICaptain! But this is `AVPlayer`'s method. An can you please tell me, if I will use `AVPlayer`, how then I can stop the video? What is an analog of `MPViewController`'s `endPlayBackTime` for `AVPlayer`? I need to play only a part of video.

Answer (score 1):

Use AVPlayer instead of MPMoviePlayer. It will give you more control over Media playback.

[See this (AVPlayer)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/index.html)